# New question answered by existing answer on another question

Tags: support, flags, answers

If I have asked a new question, what should I do if I then find the answer on another question, but the other question is more general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply delete your own question if it didn't receive any answers yet, or close your post as duplicate of the other one if it did.

If the other answer you found was way too general to be a duplicate, and you have plenty to tell about making it exactly fit for your question, you could post an answer, linking to the other one, and answer your own question very thoroughly.

Comment: It is already answered.

Comment: You could still vote or flag to close as duplicate and then accept that duplicate from the banner.

Comment: Thanks, I closed it as a duplicate